# How to store mouse & keyboard event and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, events, storing-data

I want to record everything a user do in a web page (click, double click, key press, scroll, ect). I also want to record when does the event happen.

What will be the best way for storing all those info. Json, arrays, object or string?

So far, I'm storing everything in a string like that:
`c|15:33:22-dc|15:32:14`
c = click
dc = double click

I need to make sure the information is easy to extract.

Comment: Each event is an object itself.  A deep copy of this object would probably be best.

Comment: @JohnHartsock If I record mouse movement, do you think it will be efficient?

Answer (score 1):

Every event in the Document Object Model is wrapped in an event object.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

If I create an onclick event one of the parameters for that function is the event.  You can record these event objects.

jQuery

```
var myEventList= [],
$('#myID').on('click', function(event) {
   myEventList.push(event);
});
```

JavaScript

```
var myEventList=[];
document.getElementById('myID').onclick = function(event) {
   myEventList.push(event)
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill try that.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to store this data?

For work/collect this events I would suggest you using the object with array inside. Like this:

```
var eventsLog = {"mouse":[],"keyboard":[]};
```

When event fired, you just push it into array. It's comfortable.

```
var insert = [new Date(), 'event_name'];
(eventsLog.mouse).push(insert);
```

And when you want to transfer data to another app, you will simply convert the data into the required format.

Comment: I want to reproduce human behavior in a webpage/app. Ill register everything and play it back. Everything need to be in a sort of timeline. If I store everything in object/array I think Ill have do a lot of manipulation in order to reproduce the user behavior.
When I say 'play it back' I mean that you will see a fake mouse in the screen reproducing what you just did. Same thing for the typing in a form field.

Comment: Ok. It gives us two points: First: Time goes ahead and all what we put in array will be sorted by time by default (first key (event) - 0, second (event) - 1, and etc). Second: you can use object with a key like "time" format (Date.now()).

Comment: If you have some types of event, which you will use in your playback, you can drop events in appropriate object: `var eventsLog = {'form_1':{'input_1':['event_1'],['event_2']}}`. And then you can take exactly what you need, it will be faster and simply. `var fill_form = eventsLog.form_1.input_1;` You can form your object as you need. And I am still interesting where do you want to store this data (browser, data base or something other)? Much may depend on it.

Comment: Great ill try that. For now, everything is localhost. All the data will be stored in data.js. You lost the data when you refresh.
Step 2, store the data on mongoDB. The user will click on 'start' and this will create a session id. All the data between start and end will be stored under this session id.

Comment: In this case you need to use something like a date base. For example window.localStorage. But I recommend you use a database from the start of development. It will give you much more flexibility. You will can Sort and Group data by the session_id, time_period, type_of_event, and etc. Anyway it is very big work. Maybe you may want to look in the direction of ready solutions with a ready-made API, like a Google Analytics or something similar?

Comment: Naaah!! I'll do everything myself. The idea is to learn how to do it in order to improve my skills ;)
Maybe it will lead to something interesting later. We'll see...
I also want to make sure I do not rely on third party. I'm afraid it will affect the performance.
I'll take your recommendation and store the data in DB directly.

Comment: Do you think it's still a good solution if I want to record the mouse movements? This will create a LOT of entry.

Comment: Oh, it's a very difficult story. To make a real effective app you'll need create a very smart application and to provide a plenty of events, such as what if mouse stop, mouse move, mouse speed, mouse is out of the browser and etc.

Comment: I mean, for example, when mouse stop or inactivity, you must stop recording and wait for resuming, and then write the track by the timestamp of the events (from stop to stop it will be a point). Thereafter you'll get a pretty data base, and can give fast and clean respond. You can looking for some like a "geo tracking", "store tracking data"... And finally, all of it be depend of the final goal. Good luck!

Comment: I already have a plan for the logic. Thats the fun part. Hopefully with your tips everything will work just fine. Thanks a lot.